# Coordinates conversion with mapbox

Tags: vue.js, coordinates, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Does mapbox support coordinates only in the following format, as numbers? `[-58.5003038, -34.5741957]`

My coordinates are saved in the DB as this format of number and direction `1010N 09710W` and if I put them directly on the map, I get `Error: Invalid LngLat object: (NaN, NaN)`

How can I convert them to some format that mapbox supports?

I am using Mapbox GL JS and [VueMapbox](https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/) that is basically mapboxGL JS for Vue

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mapbox only supports coordinates as decimal degrees. Your coordinates are likely in some other projection (which you will need to figure out), and you will need to convert them with something like proj4js. You might try asking on gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: im trying to use my own latitude longitude coordinates via navigator. im getting an error "Invalid LngLat latitude value: must be between -90 and 90" even though my latitude value is 49.1733806. even if the coordinates do not corespond to the correct location because im using a globe projection, 49... is still within the -90 to 90 range... any idea what is happening here?